# Is reparenting from the shell possible?

Tags: process, exec, namespace

This question is closely related to [How to "correctly" start an application from a shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152310/how-to-correctly-start-an-application-from-a-shell) but tries to tackle a more specific problem. How can I spawn an application from a shell and thereby making it a child of another process. Here is what I mean exemplified with two graphics:

```
systemd-+-acpid
        |-bash---chromium-+-chrome-sandbox---chromium-+-chrome-sandbox---nacl_helper
        |                 |                           `-chromium---5*[chromium-+-{Chrome_ChildIOT}]
        |                 |                                                    |-{Compositor}]
        |                 |                                                    |-{HTMLParserThrea}]
        |                 |                                                    |-{OptimizingCompi}]
        |                 |                                                    `-3*[{v8:SweeperThrea}]]
        |                 |-chromium
        |                 |-chromium-+-chromium
        |                 |          |-{Chrome_ChildIOT}
        |                 |          `-{Watchdog}
        |                 |-{AudioThread}
        |                 |-3*[{BrowserBlocking}]
        |                 |-{BrowserWatchdog}
        |                 |-5*[{CachePoolWorker}]
        |                 |-{Chrome_CacheThr}
        |                 |-{Chrome_DBThread}
        |                 |-{Chrome_FileThre}
        |                 |-{Chrome_FileUser}
        |                 |-{Chrome_HistoryT}
        |                 |-{Chrome_IOThread}
        |                 |-{Chrome_ProcessL}
        |                 |-{Chrome_SafeBrow}
        |                 |-{CrShutdownDetec}
        |                 |-{IndexedDB}
        |                 |-{LevelDBEnv}
        |                 |-{NSS SSL ThreadW}
        |                 |-{NetworkChangeNo}
        |                 |-2*[{Proxy resolver}]
        |                 |-{WorkerPool/1201}
        |                 |-{WorkerPool/2059}
        |                 |-{WorkerPool/2579}
        |                 |-{WorkerPool/2590}
        |                 |-{WorkerPool/2592}
        |                 |-{WorkerPool/2608}
        |                 |-{WorkerPool/2973}
        |                 |-{WorkerPool/2974}
        |                 |-{chromium}
        |                 |-{extension_crash}
        |                 |-{gpu-process_cra}
        |                 |-{handle-watcher-}
        |                 |-{inotify_reader}
        |                 |-{ppapi_crash_upl}
        |                 `-{renderer_crash_}
        |-2*[dbus-daemon]
        |-dbus-launch
        |-dhcpcd
        |-firefox-+-4*[{Analysis Helper}]
        |         |-{Cache I/O}
        |         |-{Cache2 I/O}
        |         |-{Cert Verify}
        |         |-3*[{DOM Worker}]
        |         |-{Gecko_IOThread}
        |         |-{HTML5 Parser}
        |         |-{Hang Monitor}
        |         |-{Image Scaler}
        |         |-{JS GC Helper}
        |         |-{JS Watchdog}
        |         |-{Proxy R~olution}
        |         |-{Socket Thread}
        |         |-{Timer}
        |         |-{URL Classifier}
        |         |-{gmain}
        |         |-{localStorage DB}
        |         |-{mozStorage #1}
        |         |-{mozStorage #2}
        |         |-{mozStorage #3}
        |         |-{mozStorage #4}
        |         `-{mozStorage #5}
        |-gpg-agent
        |-login---bash---startx---xinit-+-Xorg.bin-+-xf86-video-inte
        |                               |          `-{Xorg.bin}
        |                               `-dwm-+-dwmstatus
        |                                     `-xterm---bash-+-bash
        |                                                    `-pstree
        |-systemd---(sd-pam)
        |-systemd-journal
        |-systemd-logind
        |-systemd-udevd
        |-wpa_actiond
        `-wpa_supplicant
```

The process tree shows chromium and firefox as children of the `init` process that starts at boot and has `PID 1`. But what I want to achieve is to start firefox and chromium as children of `dwm`. Hence, I want a similar behaviour to what you can see under the `weston` part of the following process tree where firefox has `weston-desktop` as its parent:

```
systemd-+-acpid
        |-bash---chromium-+-chrome-sandbox---chromium-+-chrome-sandbox---nacl_helper
        |                 |                           `-chromium-+-3*[chromium-+-{Chrome_ChildIOT}]
        |                 |                                      |             |-{Compositor}]
        |                 |                                      |             |-{HTMLParserThrea}]
        |                 |                                      |             |-{OptimizingCompi}]
        |                 |                                      |             `-3*[{v8:SweeperThrea}]]
        |                 |                                      `-4*[chromium-+-{Chrome_ChildIOT}]
        |                 |                                                    |-{CompositorRaste}]
        |                 |                                                    |-{Compositor}]
        |                 |                                                    |-{HTMLParserThrea}]
        |                 |                                                    |-{OptimizingCompi}]
        |                 |                                                    `-3*[{v8:SweeperThrea}]]
        |                 |-{AudioThread}
        |                 |-3*[{BrowserBlocking}]
        |                 |-{BrowserWatchdog}
        |                 |-5*[{CachePoolWorker}]
        |                 |-{Chrome_CacheThr}
        |                 |-{Chrome_DBThread}
        |                 |-{Chrome_FileThre}
        |                 |-{Chrome_FileUser}
        |                 |-{Chrome_HistoryT}
        |                 |-{Chrome_IOThread}
        |                 |-{Chrome_ProcessL}
        |                 |-{Chrome_SafeBrow}
        |                 |-{Chrome_SyncThre}
        |                 |-{CrShutdownDetec}
        |                 |-{IndexedDB}
        |                 |-{NSS SSL ThreadW}
        |                 |-{NetworkChangeNo}
        |                 |-2*[{Proxy resolver}]
        |                 |-{WorkerPool/2315}
        |                 |-{WorkerPool/2316}
        |                 |-{WorkerPool/2481}
        |                 |-{chromium}
        |                 |-{extension_crash}
        |                 |-{gpu-process_cra}
        |                 |-{handle-watcher-}
        |                 |-{inotify_reader}
        |                 |-{renderer_crash_}
        |                 `-{sandbox_ipc_thr}
        |-2*[dbus-daemon]
        |-dbus-launch
        |-dhcpcd
        |-gpg-agent
        |-login---bash---startx---xinit-+-Xorg.bin-+-xf86-video-inte
        |                               |          `-{Xorg.bin}
        |                               `-dwm-+-dwmstatus
        |                                     `-xterm---bash
        |-login---bash---weston-launch---weston-+-Xwayland---4*[{Xwayland}]
        |                                       |-weston-desktop--+-firefox-+-firefox
        |                                       |                 |         |-4*[{Analysis Helper}]
        |                                       |                 |         |-{Cache2 I/O}
        |                                       |                 |         |-{Cert Verify}
        |                                       |                 |         |-{DNS Resolver #1}
        |                                       |                 |         |-{DNS Resolver #2}
        |                                       |                 |         |-2*[{DOM Worker}]
        |                                       |                 |         |-{Gecko_IOThread}
        |                                       |                 |         |-{HTML5 Parser}
        |                                       |                 |         |-{Hang Monitor}
        |                                       |                 |         |-{Image Scaler}
        |                                       |                 |         |-{ImageDecoder #1}
        |                                       |                 |         |-{ImageDecoder #2}
        |                                       |                 |         |-{ImageDecoder #3}
        |                                       |                 |         |-{JS GC Helper}
        |                                       |                 |         |-{JS Watchdog}
        |                                       |                 |         |-{Socket Thread}
        |                                       |                 |         |-{Timer}
        |                                       |                 |         |-{URL Classifier}
        |                                       |                 |         |-{gmain}
        |                                       |                 |         |-{localStorage DB}
        |                                       |                 |         |-{mozStorage #1}
        |                                       |                 |         |-{mozStorage #2}
        |                                       |                 |         |-{mozStorage #3}
        |                                       |                 |         |-{mozStorage #4}
        |                                       |                 |         `-{mozStorage #5}
        |                                       |                 `-weston-terminal---bash---pstree
        |                                       `-weston-keyboard
        |-systemd---(sd-pam)
        |-systemd-journal
        |-systemd-logind
        |-systemd-udevd
        |-tmux---bash
        |-wpa_actiond
        `-wpa_supplicant
```

One possible solution would be to use `nsenter` from `util-linux`. I could enter the namespace of the `dwm` process and fork a new firefox process which would then be the child of `dwm`. However, that seems like a lot of work. Is there some easier way to do this?

Comment: If you launch firefox from a dwm keybind (using the `spawn` function), it will parent the process...

Comment: Basically I would like to do this for every application. Hence, this would involve setting keybinds for every relevant application in `dwm`'s `config.h`. I'd prefer to avoid this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not start a process as the child of the shell, and then "reparent" it so another process becomes it's parent.

So you need to use a parent process that explicitly starts the children.

`init` with PID 1 is an exception, processes can become it's child as it collects processes that lost their original parent process.

(With upstart, there can be multiple `init` processes, they do not share the PID 1, but otherwise the roles are very similar.)
(See also [`PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER in man 2 prctl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man2/prctl.2.html))

Comment: Cheers. As far as I know you can actually do this since Linux kernel 3.4 by setting `PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER` which circumvents `init` picking up orphan processes. But I think it's just to complicated for my case. (cf. `man prctl`).

Comment: Scary! *shudder* ...in many ways...

Comment: `init` with other PIDs as well. Upstart creates an init for each user session, IIRC, which serves as the parent for that session's orphaned processes.

Comment: The question for me is: How can is it possible to get the following process tree from the shell: `systemd--bash--firefox`. All methods I try will ultimately lead to a process tree of the following form `systemd--firefox` when I spawn firefox from the shell.

Comment: That looks like you did an `exec`, replacing the `bash` process by the `firefox` process?

Comment: Exactly. But somehow launchers like `dmenu` manage to "demonize" a `/bin/bash` process which is the parent of the program. In the `pstree`s I posted `chromium` has not `init` as its parent but rather `bash` which in turn has `init` as parent. This `bash` session however is not attached to any terminal (that's why I say "demonized") and I wonder how this works...

Comment: I just tried `sleep 101 & sleep 102 & sleep 103 &` in a terminal - I get a shell that is parent to these sleep processes, I think. Do you mean it's different if there is no terminal?

Comment: If I run sleep in a shell, in foreground, I also see the shell as a parent in pstree.

Comment: Yes, but as soon as you exit the terminal with `exit` you kill the shell with it. Hence, the now orphaned processes get adopted by `init`. Which is exactly what we talked about before and how it is not possible to reparent. But how then is the aforementioned `pstree` output for chromium possible.

Comment: With exit, you exit the shell. Try a script that runs some commands in background, and then one in foreground. And run that in background, disown it, exit the terminal. (somewhat confusing...)

Comment: `dmenu_run`, the script that launches the programm, actually just contains: `dmenu_path | dmenu "$@" | ${SHELL:-"/bin/sh"} &` where the first two commands are just there to pipe the name of the program to the shell.

Comment: I remember vaguely that there may be a special case when the shell has just that one command to run, and may use `exec` only then. Let's see...

Comment: Hmm.. I tried `strace -f -o sh-one-command.strace bash -c '/bin/true'` and `strace -f -o sh-two-commands.strace bash -c '/bin/false; /bin/true'` - they look about the same regarding exec. Not sure where I have seen that...

Answer (score 5):

What you ask for is simply impossible. By the design of the Unix and Linux internal process management `init` becomes the parent of all processes whose parents die. This is because processes must have parents (also by design), and init is always there, for if `init` dies, the system shuts down. But beyond that there is no such thing as "re-parenting" processes.

**EDIT**

**However:** As lord.garbage pointed out, there's the arcane `prctl()` system call which is wicked cool and makes any program that uses it unportable. Suppose we don't care. Using the `PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER` option it can `wait()` not only for its own children (as before) but also for all of their descendants, should their parents die prematurely. Thus a process using this feature can assume the role of `init` for its descendants. The following code is a proof of concept:

```
#include        <sys/prctl.h>
#include        <sys/wait.h>
#include        <unistd.h>
#include        <stdio.h>

int
main (int argc, const char* const argv[], char* const envp[])
{
        pid_t   pid;

        if (prctl(PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER, 1, 0, 0, 0) < 0) {
                perror("prctl");
                return 4;
        }
        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0) {
                perror("fork");
                return 4;
        }
        if (pid == 0) {
                // child
                char* const argv[] = { "/usr/bin/konsole", "-e", "/bin/bash", NULL };
                if (execve("/usr/bin/konsole", argv, envp) < 0) {
                        perror("execve");
                }
        }

        // parent
        while (1) {
                pid_t   wpid;
                int     s;

                wpid = waitpid(-1, &s, 0);
                if (wpid > 0) {
                        printf("child with pid %u has exited\n", wpid);
                }
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Run some programs in the background that does not need shell attendance, exit konsole, run `ps`, exit the programs, and see what happens. Replace `konsole` by anything your heart desires.

Now, in order to achieve what you want, use the `prctl()` call as in the PoC and then `execve()` to `dwm`. And hope that `dwm` `wait()`s for unspecific children lest they end up as zombies.

**Final note:** There's still no such thing as re-parenting. I.e. you still cannot arbitrarily assign a parent to a process.

Comment: Cheers. See comments/discussion above to @Volker's answer.

Comment: I did not get notified about your edit so I just read this now. Thank you, @countermode.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can send a process to the dwm process as parent. But if you could start a screen or shell as a child process of dwm, then you could reparent your desired processes into that. See this link for details: http://monkeypatch.me/blog/move-a-running-process-to-a-new-screen-shell.html

Comment: More details are needed. Blogs come and go, SE stays here. Please include the walkthrough from the linked article into your post.

Comment: As @DeerHunter feared, the blog entry is now gone, it seems. Here's an archived version: http://web.archive.org/web/20160504140857/http://monkeypatch.me/blog/move-a-running-process-to-a-new-screen-shell.html

Answer (score 0):

With [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr), you can reparent a running program to a new terminal. [Here](https://blog.nelhage.com/2011/02/changing-ctty/) is a longer explanation how it works.