# nohup, screen and tmux not working when closing connection on yocto linux (intel edison)

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen, nohup, tmux

I have an Intel Edison with Yocto Linux and standard configurations. It had nohup pre-installed and I managed to install both screen and tmux (by compiling them from sources).
Now, I would like to run some process and keep it working when I disconnect. I tried the following:

- Running a program with screen, detaching, logging out, logging in, running `screen -r`
- Running a program with tmux, detaching, logging out, logging in, running `tmux attach`
- Running that program with `nohup python myscript.py &`

When using screen and tmux, I succesfully manage to resume my sessions if I don't disconnect. However, when I disconnect both screen and tmux say that there is no session / screen to be resumed. When running with nohup, logging out and back in causes my process to be killed (it doesn't show up when running top).

What could be going on? I really an not understanding this.

Comment: Can you log in with two different users simultaneously so that you can find out whether the detached processes are killed on log out or on the next log in? I am not familiar with Yocto Linux (i.e. I never heard of it before) but it seems to me that this is a distro problem and not related to `screen`, `tmux` or `nohup`.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to “correctly” start an application from a shell](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/152310/80216).

Answer (score 0):

mhahn said there was a bug in Yocto sshd killing all current cgroup processes when leaving ssh which has an easy fix (just didn't make it to the Edison build yet): poky - Poky Build Tool and Metadata
i.e. in short:

```
echo "KillMode=process" >> /lib/systemd/system/sshd@.service
```

https://communities.intel.com/thread/57402?start=15&tstart=0

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.