# GUI program runs from terminal but not from program launcher

Tags: terminal, x11, window-manager, gtk, launcher

I have a nice GUI program which runs fine if I start it from terminal but does not start at all if I run it from a non-terminal program launcher like `dmenu` or `gmrun`. Everytime I do so, nothing observable happens (neither on screen or in some log) but a defunct zombie process is the only trace I see so far. I tried also [several possible commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152310/how-to-correctly-start-an-application-from-a-shell) to start it from [9menu](https://github.com/arnoldrobbins/9menu) where I use */bin/bash* as the shell to run the command. Currently, I am stuck and wondering where to look next for a possible solution.

Since the program runs fine from terminal, I assume it has nothing to do with my—admittedly—unconventional and outdated setup? Where should I look first, wxWidgets, locale, …?

This is my environment:

- Debian 3.2.102-1 i686 GNU/Linux
- The GUI program: [treesheets](https://github.com/aardappel/treesheets) (compiled by myself, using wxWidgets 3.1.4)
- Window manager: I tried with [dwm](https://dwm.suckless.org/) and [2bwm](https://github.com/venam/2bwm)

Any hint would be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find the decisive hint by inspecting the command run of *treesheets* which results in a zombie process using `strace`. In fact, I stumbled over the same problem with another C++ program.

The root cause is quite common and was revealed by the *strace* log: the library path for **libstdc++.so.6** was wrong (outdated). Running the program from shell was no problem because there I had an environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` which includes the path `/usr/local/lib` to my updated, manual installation of glibc. But this environment was not present when running a command `.xsession`.

So, to fix my problem

- either prepend `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib` to the command in `.xsession`
- add the proper linking flag during the build process in the Makefile (eg. add `-Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib,--enable-new-dtags` to `LDFLAGS` (in case of a CMake project: add `set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "/usr/local/lib")` to CMakeLists.txt)