# Process without a controlling terminal

Tags: controlling-terminal

What happens with process when it is run without a controlling terminal? How is that process different from a standard processes? What features does it lose and what does it acquire?

**UPDATE #1**

The question listed as a possible duplicate: [Concept of controlling terminal in Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58186/concept-of-controlling-terminal-in-unix) doesn't contain the answer. Also that other question is too broad and doesn't mention process qualities at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concept of controlling terminal in Unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58186/concept-of-controlling-terminal-in-unix)

Comment: This doesn't seem like a duplicate to me on the grounds that he's asking for the specific mechanics as to how this works. There is a potential for both questions to be answered by a single answer that shows the specifics of what the accepted answer in the dup is describing at a high level. If such an answer were to materialize then these 2 Q's could be marked as dups of one another. I'll bring attention to a link on the other Q as a good start to this: http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php.

Comment: @slm, thanks. The question may sound lame, but so far my understanding of Linux internals (signals, IPC etc.) is very vague, so all descriptions of `controlling terminal` are overly confusing. However, process concept is simple, so I hope it serve as an entrypoint to dig further.

Comment: @anatolytechtonik - question is a fair one. I think you'll find that the only difference b/w a controlling terminal and one that's not is that the STDIN/STDOUT/STDERR are not connected to a TTY along with a few other esoteric bits in the process group etc. as described in the other Q's accepted A'er.

Comment: You may find some useful info in [Does keyboard input always go through a controlling terminal?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/351064)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much.

Mostly a process without a controlling terminal is not subject to receiving (mostly job control related) signals from terminal events.

These would include `SIGINT`, interrupting the foreground process (group) if the interrupt character is received (usually ^C); `SIGTTIN`/`SIGTTOU` stopping the process if it tries I/O to the terminal from the background, and; `SIGHUP` telling the controlling process (the shell) to terminate, in when the terminal sees a disconnection. (Originally a modem hangup.)

[The standard has the details](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html) if you like.

Comment: Thanks. I will appreciate if the explanation won't include word "terminal", if that at all possible, because it assumes a lot of knowledge about underlying subsystem. Maybe there is an image that shows how signals travel to a process from ...? Human?