# Is `controlling terminal` solely for user control?

Tags: user-interface, controlling-terminal

I can kill processes and send signals to them with `kill`, so I don't need `controlling terminal` (or `ctty`) for that. So.. is the purpose of `controlling terminal` is solely for reacting to nudges from user? Transforming `Ctrl-C` key press into `SIGINT` ("hey, stop it!") and detecting if operator behind the keyboard is still alive ("keyboard is detached - `SIGHUP`, man")?

[The docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html#tag_11_01_03) are full with details that doesn't answer the question "why it is here?", which must be obvious for everybody except me.

Comment: What happens when you run, say, `ls` without a controlling terminal?

Comment: @SatoKatsura, good question. I don't know how to run commands without a controlling terminal yet.

Comment: Could that be because running programs such as `ls` without a controlling terminal is less than useful?

Comment: @SatoKatsura IIUC `ls` can be run from a `cron` job for some automation, and my guess is that `cron` is run without `ctty`. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/352442/process-without-a-controlling-terminal?rq=1 may have more info about processes without `ctty`.

Comment: Right.  Now, how do you add a `cron` job without a controlling terminal?

Comment: A better approach: can you run a terminal without a controlling terminal?

Comment: @SatoKatsura I don't know. I can only guess it is possible to supply some other kind of terminal for user input, and `kill` it if necessary by `pid`.